# Meteor + React + Blueprintjs font issues

Tags: reactjs, meteor, blueprintjs

I have blueprint 90% working, and am able to implement the features - except for the icon library.  I've tried several other UI toolkits, and this is the first one which I've had Icon issues with.

I have tried dumping the icons and CSS files directly into my meteor client folder and relinked the CSS dependencies, so it shouldn't be a file access issue.  I would just use a different icon library, but it's a lot of work to re-link everything through the CSS file

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Icons16";
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: url("icons-16.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("icons-16.woff") format("woff"), url("icons-16.ttf") format("truetype"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I don't understand the actual issue you're facing. I haven't used Meteor in some time, either, so I can't help there.

We use [postcss-copy-assets](https://github.com/shutterstock/postcss-copy-assets) in our build to ensure that the font files and other images used in the CSS files get copied to the correct place at build time.